# Two columns, align text of the first column (using multicols package)

Tags: multicol, multicolumn

I'm writing a document and i want two column section to write a text. I use multicol package, but if the text of the first column is shorter than the second, the first text will align to the bottom  of the second text.

How can i have the first text on the top?

I want the line1 of sec 1 align with line1 of sec2

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{Title}
\author{CE}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\section{sec1} 
line1 \\

\columnbreak

\section{sec 2}
line 1 \\
line 2 \\
line 3 \\
line 4

\end{multicols}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please add an entire compileable code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @AndréC I add the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify this with the command `\raggedcolumns`

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\title{Title}
\author{CE}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{flushleft}
\begin{multicols}{2}\raggedcolumns% <--- add these 
\section{sec1}


line1 

\columnbreak

\section{sec 2}
line 1 

line 2

line 3

line 4

\end{multicols}
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thank you !!